# "sqlplus": executable file not found in $PATH" when running a command with docker exec

Tags: oracle, docker

I want to start a Docker-container with Oracle XE and then run an SQL script (ddl.sql) to create some tables.

If I execute all the steps separately, everything works:

```
$ docker run -d --name db --rm -p 49161:1521 -v "C:/data/workspace/vpk/":/home/vpk -e ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
```

Run a terminal in container:

```
$ docker exec -it db bash
```

Execute the script:

```
root@f3ae34d554af:/# echo exit | sqlplus system/oracle@xe @/home/vpk/ddl.sql
```

However when I tried to combine the last two steps into one:

```
$ docker exec db sqlplus system/oracle@xe @/home/vpk/ddl.sql
```

I got the error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"sqlplus\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Using the full path of sqlplus didn't help either:

```
$ docker exec db bash -c "/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus system/oracle@xe /home/vpk/ddl.sql"
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

What is the reason of the error?

With the help of @maxm I was able to successfully run:

```
docker exec -it db /bin/bash -c "ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus system/oracle@xe @/home/vpk/ddl.sql"
```

However I would like to exit the sqlplus prompt afterwards. But when I tried to add `echo exit` to it and run:

```
docker exec -it db /bin/bash -c "ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe; echo exit | /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus system/oracle@xe @/home/vpk/ddl.sql"
```

I got the error:

```
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

Comment: download the Oracle instant client(which includes sqlplus ) in your local and access the database in the container.

Comment: @KaushikNayak
I want to do everything in a shell script without any installations. As the first 3 commands shown the db can be created. So no additional tools are required.

Comment: Did your container installed sql plus? And the path included sql plus. You can try echo $PATH or which sqlplus to confirm it is exist in container.

Comment: `SP2-0750` indicates that the `oraenv` script was not "sourced" -- it is usually done in a .profile/.bash_profile; it sets ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID, PATH, and others based on certain environment variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sqlplus` bin location is added to your PATH in the .bashrc, see this line in the [setup](https://github.com/wnameless/docker-oracle-xe-11g/blob/64ded1383d497c54681fe3ec4049b43068ca43a2/assets/setup.sh#L28):

```
echo 'export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

When you run exec directly without calling `bash` it's going to try and run the command with `sh -c` and the .bashrc won't be loaded. Try running this to run the file directly:

```
docker exec db /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus system/oracle@xe @/home/vpk/ddl.sql
```

I also though running with `bash -c "command"` might load .bashrc, but it doesn't seem to, might want to read up on how bash loads the .bashrc file.

Edit:

As referenced in the comment below ORACLE_HOME isn't set. This command should work:

```
docker exec -it db /bin/bash -c "ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus system/oracle@xe /home/vpk/ddl.sql"
```

Comment: Please, see edited question. I've just put the execution result. There must be some root problem. Maybe wrong user... that's why "sqlplus" and other files aren't "seen".

Comment: Hmm, this is quite verbose, but this works: `docker exec -it db /bin/bash -c "ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus system/oracle@xe /home/vpk/ddl.sql"`

Comment: `source /etc/bash.bashrc` should also work, but I can't seem to get it to set the correct env vars during the session

Comment: maxm
Your command works. But I would like to exit the sqplus prompt afterwards. I've edited my question. Please, see the last commands there.

Comment: Hmm, I think if you just remove the `-it` from the command SQL won't spawn a shell and the command will exit.

Comment: maxm, thank you. Please, post your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it may seem a little "silly" on my part, but remember to allow time for the instance to finish being instantiated. The 12c Enterprise Edition, p. eg, takes around 10min to be instantiated completely and the database created for use